# Cannot set two or more cookies in HTTPoison

Tags: cookies, elixir

when I try to set 2 or more cookies I give only the first one

```
case HTTPoison.get("https://httpbin.org/cookies", %{}, hackney: [cookie: [{"cookie1", "1"} , {"cookie2", "2"}]]) do

{:ok, %HTTPoison.Response{status_code: 200, body: body}} ->
IO.puts body
{_, %HTTPoison.Response{status_code: _, body: _}} ->
# Nothing to do
end
end
```

The answer from the page:

```
{
  "cookies": {
    "cookie1": "1"
  }
}
```

(Sorry for eventually mistakes, i cleanup a complex code for write here) :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why your example does not work, but `hackney` can receive cookies in binary format.

```
case HTTPoison.get("https://httpbin.org/cookies", %{}, hackney: [cookie: "cookie1=111; cookie2=222"]) do
  {:ok, %HTTPoison.Response{status_code: 200, body: body}} ->
  IO.puts body
end
```

responce

```
{
  "cookies": {
    "cookie1": "111",
    "cookie2": "222"
  }
}
```

Comment: you are my hero, i expected a Keyword List but i didn't found any doc about it ...